# Android: It is impossible to input into editText text after crop image

Tags: android-edittext, crop

My interface consists of two parts: editText and imageView used to show image
I use *intent* **MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE** to take photo, then *intent* **com.android.camera.action.CROP** is used to crop that photo.

After cropping, Inputting text into editText but can't be performed though keyboard is displayed (sometimes i can input)

If i input text into edit text before cropping, this manipulation is performed normally.

I tried setting focus for editText but this problem was not solved:

```
    editText.setEnabled(true);
    editText.requestFocus();
    editText.setFocusable(true);
    editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Hope for your help.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.csdn.net/mmorss/article/details/19190833

I found this blog, it says, adding an invisble edittext would fix your problem. And I tried it, success.

Following is how I did it:

1. I add this extra edittext named et_none:

   ```
   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/et_none"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
       android:background="@drawable/bg_white_box"
       android:gravity="top"
       android:inputType="textMultiLine"
       android:padding="10dp" />
   ```
2. After crop, I add this code:

   et_none.requestFocus();

And this bug never appear.

This bug only appear on Htc G11 at about every two times.